# Is it possible to have our windows Handheld application as a USB receiver?

Tags: c#, usb, windows-embedded-compact, umdf

apologies if the question is quite basic, I am inexperienced in USB programming and I might be missing some conceptual detail here.

For our industrial solution we are supposed to provide communication between our PC wpf application and windows embedded HH 8.1 application. Ideally we would like this to be over USB.

I see a lot of [sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn312121.aspx) to connect directly to USB devices from host role.

However in our case the Windows Embedded HH device (Panasonic FZ-E1) will have the device role listening. I could not find any way to register to raw data sent from our PC application via USB events. I examined UMDF (user mode driver framework) which has examples about writing drivers for usb devices, yet it seems like it is for device manufacturers and us not being the manufacturer for Panasonic HH we should not/cannot use our own driver and we have to use the WinUSB driver it already has in place.

Windows Embedded 8.1 HH has some USB apis unlike windows phone, yet all the functionality provided in the API seems like connecting to external USB devices with the host role. When we use USBlyzer I see that there is some USB traffic towards the device from the PC so it looks it should be possible for the HH to have the listening device role. What am I missing here, any ideas?

Any help/direction is greatly appreciated.

P.S: I also tried windows connectivity api examining the source code of windows phone power tools yet it seems like the the dlls for [addon packages here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513877(v=vs.90).aspx) to handle transfer via agents is not there for newer versions of windows phone anymore.